# Django Admin is not showing list and filter options

Tags: django, django-admin

When I get yo the Admin site, the models page is not showing my list_display or filter options.

I can get in a model and change database info, that seems to work ok. It just seems not to recognizes my setup.

It used to work just fine, I don´t know exactly when in my app update this started happening.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ProductosBase, Marcas, Categorias_Producto

admin.site.register(ProductosBase)

class ProductosBaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('marca', "categoria_producto", "producto", "color", "foto_1")
    list_filter = ('marca', "categoria_producto", "producto")
    fields = (("codigo_kinemed", 'marca'), ("categoria_producto", "producto"), ("color", "packaging"), ("ancho", "largo"), ("units_inner", "inner_master", "tier"), "descripcion", "foto_1", "foto_2", "video_link")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

admin.site.register(Marcas)

class Marcas(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = 'marcas'
    fields = ['marcas']

admin.site.register(Categorias_Producto)

class Categorias_Producto(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = 'Categorias_Producto'
    `enter code here`fields = ['Categorias_Producto']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the `ModelAdmin` subclass with the `register` call.

```
class ProductosBaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('marca', "categoria_producto", "producto", "color", "foto_1")
    list_filter = ('marca', "categoria_producto", "producto")
    fields = (("codigo_kinemed", 'marca'), ("categoria_producto", "producto"), ("color", "packaging"), ("ancho", "largo"), ("units_inner", "inner_master", "tier"), "descripcion", "foto_1", "foto_2", "video_link")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

admin.site.register(ProductosBase, ProductosBaseAdmin)

class MarcasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = 'marcas'
    fields = ['marcas']

admin.site.register(Marcas, MarcasAdmin)
```